# Select count for each day in a month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sms tracker database with a date column in the format 02/25/2018 04:12:52 pm. I want to count the no of sms sent each day to display it in bar chart. 
I could only count sms sent by a user using this query "SELECT count(*) as user_count from `table` where username = 'CTC01'". How can i get an array of count for each day in a particular month

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52014569/2469308
If it works for you, you can mark it as accepted answer

Comment: A sensible step would be to first fix your date column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OP's `date_column` is `VARCHAR` type. We use [STR_TO_DATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) function:

```
SELECT DATE(STR_TO_DATE(date_column, "%m/%d/%Y %r")), COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY DATE(STR_TO_DATE(date_column, "%m/%d/%Y %r"));
```

Use [DATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date.asp) function, to convert a datetime expression to a date. Then use `GROUP BY` to get [COUNT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) datewise.

In case, you want to get data for a specific user (eg: **CTC01**) and datewise. You can do the following:

```
SELECT DATE(STR_TO_DATE(date_column, "%m/%d/%Y %r")), COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE username = 'CTC01' 
GROUP BY DATE(STR_TO_DATE(date_column, "%m/%d/%Y %r"));
```

Comment: I'm getting the total count of sms sent by that user

Comment: How do i get count for each day in an array so i can use those values for my bar graph

Comment: @MohammedShoaib can u give specific output required with column structure, so that I can update my answer. Current queries already give the data daywise.

Comment: The problem is with my column type. It is varchar and in the format 02/25/2018 04:12:52 pm. I m not able to convert it to datetime type. If i copy the values to a new column it is copying in the format dd mm yyyy and all values become 00 00 0000 00 00 00

Comment: check DATE_FORMAT function. I am meanwhile updating my answer also.

Comment: @MohammedShoaib edited the answer - please check the EDIT part

Answer (score 1):

I see your date format is `'m/d/Y H:i:s'`. So, to get the total for each day in a month, you have to do a comparison against the least time in that month and the highest time in that month. So, the query for February 2018 would be:

```
SELECT DATE(date_column), COUNT(*) 
FROM jobs
where created_on >= '02/01/2018 00:00:00' and created_on < '03/01/2018 00:00:00'
GROUP BY DATE(date_column);
```

To get for a particular user, simply append a where clause to the query above like so:

```
SELECT DATE(date_column), COUNT(*) 
FROM jobs
where created_on >= '02/01/2018 00:00:00' and created_on < '03/01/2018 00:00:00' and username = 'CTC01'
GROUP BY DATE(date_column);
```

**EDIT**
Since your date column is varchar, you first have to convert it to datetime. So run this query instead:

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_column, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')) as Date, COUNT(*) 
FROM jobs
where created_on >= '02/01/2018 00:00:00' and created_on < '03/01/2018 00:00:00'
GROUP BY DATE(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_column, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s'));
```

Comment: I'm getting this array [{"DATE(date_time)":null,"COUNT(*)":"713"}]

Comment: Also my column type is varchar, is there any method I can convert it to DATE type keeping date values intact

Comment: @MohammedShoaib check DATE_FORMAT function - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

Comment: Give an example of how your date column looks like.

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya 02/25/2018 04:12:52 pm